# How to copy with member access using boost

Tags: c++, boost, binding, boost-bind, boost-iterators

I have a container of As with

```
struct A { int f(); }
```

The container offers iterators and we can for this example assume it's an std::vector. So:

```
std::vector<A> As;
```

Now I want to copy the values provided by A::f into a second container

```
std::vector<int> fs;
```

Although I could simply iterate, as an exercide I tried to solve this with boost bind / boost iterator. What I tried so far is this:

```
std::copy(
     boost::make_transform_iterator
         (As.begin(), boost::bind(&A::f, _1)),
     boost::make_transform_iterator
         (As.begin(), boost::bind(&A::f, _1)),
     std::back_inserter( fs )
);
```

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change the second make_transform iterator to point to end() instead of begin(), everything appears to work.

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int f() {
        static int x = 0;
        return x++;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> As;
    As.push_back(A());
    As.push_back(A());
    As.push_back(A());

    std::vector<int> fs;

    std::copy(
            boost::make_transform_iterator(As.begin(), boost::bind(&A::f, _1)),
            boost::make_transform_iterator(As.end(),   boost::bind(&A::f, _1)),
            std::back_inserter(fs)
            );

    for (int const & x : fs)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

### Output

```
0
1
2
```

### Alternative Solutions

You could also solve this with a functor:

```
struct Functor {
    int operator()(A & value) const {
        return value.f();
    }
};

std::transform(As.begin(), As.end(), std::back_inserter(fs), Functor());
```

or with a lambda:

```
std::transform(As.begin(), As.end(), std::back_inserter(fs), [](A & a) { return a.f(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the function-like object you pass to `make_transform_iterator` to take an `A` and return the result of calling `f` on that `A`. While you can do this as you have done with `bind`, you can do it more explicitly with `std::mem_fn`:

```
std::copy(
  boost::make_transform_iterator
    (As.begin(), std::mem_fn(&A::f)),
  boost::make_transform_iterator
    (As.end(), std::mem_fn(&A::f)),
  std::back_inserter( fs )
);
```

Note that the second transform iterator should adapt `As.end()`.